# C# Username comparison (2 strings)

Tags: c#, mysql, string, visual-studio

Okey, so i think i'm missing something completely obvious here. I just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it, i'm tired.

I'm literally just comparing 2 string in an if statement but it doesn't think its the same.

```
public Boolean checkusn(String username)
    {
        MySqlDataReader reader = sendcmd("SELECT username FROM `users`");
        Boolean taken = true;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(reader.GetString(i) + " " + username + " ");
                if (username == reader.GetString(i))
                {
                    taken = false;
                    label17.Text = "Username already taken";
                }
                else
                {
                   taken = true;
                   label17.Text = "Username not taken";
                }

            }
        }
        return taken;
    }
```

The output is this:

```
hayhay hayhay test hayhay
```

so its comparing hayhay with hayhay and hayhay with test.
But it doesn't think them as the same....

Comment: use `string.Equals(string2)` not ==

Comment: Note that by default, text comparisons in SQL are case-insensitive, but in C# it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Your `taken = false` and `taken = true` are around the wrong way. You should learn how to use break points and how to step through code. It makes life a lot easier. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your method addressing the concerns and hopefully making it easier to maintain and understand. Changes include:

- Correct logic errors (break out of loop when found)
- Ensure passed in parameter is actually validated in some way (at least now leading / trailing spaces are removed)
- Explicitly do a case insensitive comparison (You could use string.compare if you prefer)
- Code reduction

  ```
  public bool checkusn(String username)
  {
      MySqlDataReader reader = sendcmd("SELECT username FROM `users`");
      int foundCount = 0;
      string usernamePassedIn = username.Trim().ToUpper();

      while (reader.Read() && foundCount == 0)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
          {
              string usernameReadFromDb = reader.GetString(i).Trim().ToUpper();
              if (usernamePassedIn == usernameReadFromDb)
                  foundCount++;
              if (foundCount > 0)
                  break;
          }
      }

      label17.Text = foundCount > 1 ? "Username already taken" : "Username not taken";
      return foundCount > 0;
  }
  ```

You could further improve things by returning the usernames UPPER CASED and TRIMMED from the database directly. Also note that you don't take into account the case where your parameter username may be NULL or empty.

By counting the number of times you find a match you could do other things as needed. So instead of breaking out immediately of your loops for example.

I am no expert on the MySQL reader you are using there, but as you are returning a single field it does appear a little odd that you are doing a FOR loop over the fields - I am guessing you could actually do away with your FOR loop entirely viz:

```
    public bool checkusn(String username)
    {
        MySqlDataReader reader = sendcmd("SELECT username FROM `users`");
        int foundCount = 0;
        string usernamePassedIn = username.Trim().ToUpper();

        while (reader.Read() && foundCount == 0)
        {
                string usernameReadFromDb = reader.GetString(0).Trim().ToUpper();
                if (usernamePassedIn == usernameReadFromDb)
                    foundCount++;
            }

        label17.Text = foundCount > 1 ? "Username already taken" : "Username not taken";
        return foundCount > 0;
    }
```

Comment: The for loop is there to loop over each username pulled from the database. As each result is referred to .GetString(This number to refers to each result found) So 0 would return the first result. This may seem inefficient with large databases, but i'm only an amateur :D

Comment: Isn't the Read() accessing each record from your result set? And each record has a single field? Hence looping the fields is never going to loop over more than 1 field? I am guessing your FieldCount is always 1. :-)

Comment: The field count is how many usernames there are in the database. And for read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You shoud leave the loops when taken == true.
Right now you're always returning the bool value only for the last element in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==`

From this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

> When you compare strings, you should use the methods that explicitly specify what kind of comparison you intend to perform. This makes your code much more maintainable and readable. Whenever possible, use the overloads of the methods of the System.String and System.Array classes that take a StringComparison enumeration parameter, so that you can specify which type of comparison to perform. It is best to avoid using the == and != operators when you compare strings. Also, avoid using the String.CompareTo instance methods because none of the overloads takes a StringComparison.

Comment: Someone downvoted Microsoft's own advice on this issue...brilliant.

Comment: Because the people who wrote and maintain the language must be wrong lol. I'll upvote to balance out.

Comment: when you compare string you or other values that are not `objects` use `==` when comparing object equality use the `.Equals` Method..

Comment: @MethodMan you're thinking about Java. This is not an answer because it's merely a guideline for clarity, not something that solves a hidden problem (in 99.99999% of the scenarios)

Comment: @RJM upvoted as well. Best practice is to have a default overload on framework level that implements a stringcomparison in your .Equals methods. In my own, I have IdEquals (a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) and the regular Equals w/ InvariantIgnoreCase.

Comment: it was probably down voted because it doesn't answer the question. If you want to use this as a comment, fine, but he shows what the output is. There is nothing wrong with == on strings in C#, this isn't Java. It doesn't effect what it would return in this case as he gives us the output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips guys, i dont use c# often. Although what you mentioned was not the case, it helped me find my mistake.

I was stupidly not stopping the for loop once it found the username, so as it was going over to the next username in the list it was setting it back to true.

Comment: ah, i saw your comment after Flott. Thanks!